# Quotient ring over non principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like some clarification about quotient rings when the ideal is not principal.

Let $I$ be a non principal ideal in $R$, $I = (A_1,..,A_n)$. Is it always true that $R/I$ is isomorphic to $[[[R/(A_1)]/(A_2)]/...]/(A_n)$ ?
For example during a lecture it was asked for which $k \ge 3$ the ideal $(2, 1+\sqrt{-k})$ was principal in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-k}]$. It was proved that if $2$ does not divide $1+\sqrt{-k}$ (which should be always, unless I'm missing something) the ideal was principal if and only if it was the entire ring. To study when this happens, this was the reasoning:

${\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-k}] \over(2,1+\sqrt{-k})} \cong {\Bbb Z[X] \over(2, X^2 +k, 1+x)} \cong {(\Bbb Z/(2))\over(k+1)} \cong (0)$ if $k$ even

I would like to know if it is always possible to do this, and also if someone can explain the second equality because that one confuses me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (for the first question): if $R$ is a ring and $I,J\subseteq R$ are ideals such that $I\subseteq J\subseteq R$, by the third isomoprhism theorem you have $(R/I)/(J/I)\cong R/J$.
Note that if $J=(a_1,...,a_n)$, then $(a_1)\subseteq (a_1,a_2)\subseteq ...\subseteq (a_1,...,a_n)$.
Try to figure out the answer from here.

I'll add the answer to your second question:
$${\Bbb Z[X] \over(2, X^2 +k, 1+x)} \cong {(\Bbb Z[X]/(1+X))\over([2],[X^2+k])}= {(\Bbb Z[X]/(1+X))\over([2],[1+k])} \cong{\Bbb Z\over(2,k+1)}\cong {\Bbb (Z/(2))\over(k+1)}$$
Note that in the second equality $X^2+k-(1+k)=X^2-1=(X+1)(X-1)$ so that $[X^2+k]=[1+k]$ where $[...]$ denote the equivalence class modulo $X+1$.

Comment: Ah damn, I knew it had something to do with the 3rd isomorphism theorem but of course I couldn't make the jump from theory to practice until someone spelled it out for me -.-" Thanks! I also went to check the theorem and the hypothesis says nothing about R, so this is true in every ring right?

Comment: Yes, even if in a non commutative ring I believe it becomes less relevant because the concept of principal ideal is not as "elegant" as in commutative rings since $(a)=RaR$. You can of course consider left and right principal ideals but honestly I don't know if this has any utility or applications.

Comment: I've added a solution for your second question

Comment: I've tried your way of factor away (1+x) firstly and I got immediately  the 3rd member of that chain, how did you get from 2 to [k+1]? I can see (2, X^2+k, 1+x)/(1+x) becoming ([2], [1+k]) but not the passage in the middle, don't all the integer go in different class in mod X+1?

Comment: @Prio216  yes, I made an error copying the passage. Check if it is okay now

Comment: Perfect, now i get it. Thanks for going back and adding the solution, even after clarify the use of the 3rd theorem I was having problem as I didn't understand how 1+x became 1+k... turns out it was x^2+k mod 1+x and the prof just skipped a step that wasn't obvious to me

Comment: @Prio216 You're welcome!